# How to get more data of a row which is selected by MIN()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+----------+--------------+
| id |  user_id |  reputation  |
+----+----------+--------------+
| 1  | 442      | 1000         |
| 2  | 746      | 500          |
| 3  | 843      | 800          |
| 4  | 746      | 700          |
| 5  | 442      | 300          |
+----+----------+--------------+
```

Here is my query:

```
select user_id, min(reputation) min_rep
from mytable 
group by user_id
```

And here is the result:

```
+---------+---------+
| user_id | min_rep |
+---------+---------+
| 442     | 300     |
| 746     | 500     |
| 843     | 800     |
+---------+---------+
```

Now I need to select the `id` of that row. So here is the expected result:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | min_rep |
+----+---------+---------+
| 5  | 442     | 300     |
| 2  | 746     | 500     |
| 3  | 843     | 800     |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try the below way -

```
select * from 
from mytable a where reputation = 
   (select min(reputation) from mytable b where a.userid=b.userid group by b.userid )
```

Comment: What about having duplicate rows in the table? For example **two rows** with these values `user_id = 442` and `reputation = 300`;

Comment: I have edited the answer. In case, you have same values of userid and reputation in multiple columns, you can add 'group by a.userid' at last to get single record.